# Configuring embedded H2 users for distribution

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, h2, embedded-database

I am trying to use H2 (embedded mode) to package in a ZIP file (which also contains my Java app `JAR`).  When the user runs the `JAR`, it will use the H2 database that "shipped" with the ZIP file.

How do I configure a username and password for the H2 database that can be used by my JAR for accessing data? For instance, I might want to create a username called `myapp` with a password of `12345` and supply that to my app's JDBC connection string.

But in order for JDBC to authenticate my app against the H2 DB, I first need to set up the `myapp` user in the first place. How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to connect to a database that does not exist, it is created.  See http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases

The juicy bit:

> The user that created the database automatically becomes the administrator of this database.